How to properly organize the work of overloaded methods?
I have such a situation. There are methods that conditionally take one argument and do something. For example:
public Task SomeOperation(string name)
{
    var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...);
    
    var anotherUser = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...);
    
    /// more logig
}

Now I need to make a method that will accept something as the second parameter, and depending on it, the logic will change quite a bit.
public Task SomeOperation(string name, string conString)
{
    var context = _service.CreateContext(conString);
    
    var user = await context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...);
    
    var anotherUser = await context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...);
    
    /// more logig
}

The logic hardly changes. And if you overload the methods in the services, then it changes a little, and the general logic is copied. It turns out a lot of repetitive code in the service. What should I do in such a situation? Should I put logic in a private method? Or pass the second default parameter null to these methods, and inside the condition. Are there any patterns? (The methods of the service are).

Please expand your example. In the second example, once you get the context - how is it used in the "common" code?

@Felix In the second example, a context is simply created, and in general logic, where the context from DI was used, the context we created is now used. And that's it, it's all a change.

One immediate solution I can see here is what you roughly suggested: created private method with common logic.
As I see only context change between two methods, so let's parametrize that:
public Task SomeOperation(string name, string conString)
{
    await SomeOperation(name, _service.CreateContext(conString));
}

public Task SomeOperation(string name)
{
    await SomeOperation(name, _context);
}

// And I think you could make it even static.
private Task SomeOperation(string name, Context context)
{
    var user = await context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...);
    
    var anotherUser = await context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...);
    
    // more logic
}


Yes, I also think that this option suits me. I just wondered if it was good and if there were no better options.

@Андрей I think ay other "good option" would start from here. This is good enough for start. By splitting the code into smaller bits you will start seeing more and more ways to improve it (maybe you will end up with group of methods worth placing into another class, for example maybe context creation could be placed somewhere else). Remember, premature optimization is evil - if you have performant code, don't make it more performant - similairly here - if your code is good enough, don't waste time trying to make it better, just for the sake of it.

@Андрей And if my answer was helpful, you should accept/upvote it

This is a classic example of the template method design pattern. In short we have a method which describes the core logic has some customization points. This method is considered as a template because it defines the control flow and the common stuff but leaves the hooks blank so, the derived classes can customize the logic.

Source: dofactory
As you can see this design pattern is usually implemented via inheritance. But it could be achieved without that as well.
private Task SomeOperationTemplate(string name, 
    Context context, 
    Action<Context> beforeStep = null, 
    Action<Context> afterStep = null)

{
    beforeStep?.Invoke(context);

    // common logic

    afterStep?.Invoke(context);
}

As you can see the beforeStep and afterStep are optional

They can receive any number of arbitrary parameters (up to 16)
Or they can return any value if you define them as Func instead of Action

The usage would look like this:
public async Task SomeOperation(string name, string conString)
{
    Action<Context> after = ctx => { ... };
    await SomeOperationTemplate(name, _service.CreateContext(conString), afterStep: after);
}

public async Task SomeOperation(string name)
{
    Action<Context> before = _ => { ... };
    await SomeOperationTemplate(name, _context, beforeStep: before);
}

